# Hash Password in XML - C#

Tags: c#, xml, hash, salt

I'm struggling with hashing and salting a password. I am creating an XML file which stores a person's name, card number and password. I then need to display the information from the xml file back to the console window. I was able to encrypt the card number and display it to the console and also decrypt it back to the console window, but I'm struggling with hashing and salting the password and displaying it back to the console window.

```
         UserInfo addUser = new UserInfo
        {
            CardNumber = "1234-5678-9012-3456",
            Password = "Pa$$w0rd",
            CustomerName = "Bob Smith"
        };


        XmlSerializer serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserInfo));
        string path = Combine(CurrentDirectory, "customers.xml");
        using (FileStream stream = File.Create(path))
        {

            serialize.Serialize(stream, addUser);
        }

   private static string SaltAndHashPassword(string pasword, string salt)
    {
        var sha = SHA256.Create();
        var saltedPassword = pasword + salt;
        return Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(saltedPassword)));
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt at hashing or salting. Have you tried something that isn't working?

Comment: XML has nothing to do with your task. Replace the `Password` property with the hashed value and serialize the class just like any other. Use eg [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-6.0) to securely hash the password

Answer (score 0):

You never want to store raw customer information. You need to store the salted and hashed version of the card number and password in the file. So your UserInfo class would need to be something like the following. How you do the salting and hashing is up to you (and what I'm assuming the assignment is). The part about displaying the XML file to the console is really a separate question with lots of other answers on SO.

```cs
public class UserInfo
{
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}

    public string HashedPassword {get; set;}
    public string DecryptPassword() => DecryptValue(HashedPassword);

    public string HashedCardNumber {get; set;}
    public string DecriptCardNumber() => DecryptValue(HashedCardNumber);

    /// xml serializer needs a public empty constructor
    public UserInfo() {} 

    /// this is the constructor you'll used when you add a new customer
    public UserInfo(string customerName, string password, string creditCard)
    {
        CustomerName = customerName;
        HashedPassword = HashAndSaltValue(password, "someSalt");
        HashedCreditCard = HashAndSaltValue(creditCard, "someSalt");
    }

    private static Decrypt(string value, string salt)
    {
        // unhash and unsalt value
    }

    private static string SaltAndHashPassword(string password, string salt)
    {
        var sha = SHA256.Create();
        var saltedPassword = password + salt;
        return Convert.ToBase64String(
                   sha.ComputeHash(
                     Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(saltedPassword)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have little ecommerce experience, so asking seriously. Why hash the card number? Isn't the point so that a customer can use the card "on file"? If it is hashed you cannot get the original value back. Wouldn't this be a case for encryption instead of hashing, or better yet, just don't store it at all?